# find() for std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set, std

I have a question on how the objects stored in set are compared.

```
class A
{
public:  
char * name;
};
```

I am storing objects of A in a set. I am provide a comparator class which provides implementation of operator() ( A &ob1, A & ob2 ). Here I compare ob1.name & ob2.name and return true when ob1.name is lesser than ob2.name.

Will I be able to search for an object using the find() of set ? I have provided implementation only for operator(). Will this be sufficient ? Could someone explain how find() works in this case ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's `operator(A& ob1, A& ob2)`?  Do you mean `operator<(const A& ob1, const A& ob2)`?

Comment: He probably means operator() (A&, A&).

Comment: Yes, Ivan u r right. Correcting my question.

Comment: By the way, you should make sure to release the memory pointed to by `name`, or just use a string and get it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that will be used in `std::set::find()` is an instance of the `Comparator` class that you declared as a template parameter of your set.

```
template < class Key, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<Key> > class set;
```

Concretely, the comparator instance will be passed to Key objects and should return true if the first is located before the second. So **yes, your implementation is fine.**

Now, to dig further: if you want to convince yourself, you can dig into the source code of gcc’s implementation of the standard library, and you’ll find:

```
  template<typename _Key, typename _Val, typename _KeyOfValue,
           typename _Compare, typename _Alloc>
    typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue,
              _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator
    _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::
    find(const _Key& __k)
    {
      iterator __j = _M_lower_bound(_M_begin(), _M_end(), __k);
      return (__j == end()
          || _M_impl._M_key_compare(__k, _S_key(__j._M_node))) ? end() : __j;
    }
```

You can see that `_M_key_compare` (which is an instance of the `_Compare` class you provided), is called with `__k` as a first parameter (one of your `Key`) and the return value of `_S_key(...)` which is a key. The return value of `_M_key_compare` is used in a ternary expression, so it should be a boolean.

Comment: Thanks. How is equality test done ? We have provided implementation only for < right ?

Comment: @KodeWarrior `std::set` doesn't require an equality test, only [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)

Comment: @KodeWarrior, I think it is more accurate to say that STL algorithms define "equality" (or more accurately, equivalence classes) on the basis that if neither `a < b` nor `b < a` are true, a and b are "equal" (in the same equivalence class). So `<` is all that's needed.

Comment: *So yes, your implementation is fine* -- Well, only kind of. The keys in a set are stored as `const` objects which means that the comparator needs to take the arguments by `const&`

Comment: @ rici -- Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

@David -- Thanks for your comment. This is just a sample code.

Answer (score 4):

> Will I be able to search for an object using the find() of set ? I have provided implementation only for operator(). Will this be sufficient ?

Yes, it will be sufficient to provide only `comparator` class with implementation for `operator ()(A&,A&)` only. See default comparator `std::less<>`.

> Could someone explain how find() works in this case ?

Very simple speaking: `std::set<T,comparator>::find(k)` returns iterator `it` if and only if both comparison fails:

1. false == comparator(k,*it)
2. false == comparator(*it, k)

Otherwise it returns `std::set<>::end()`...

---

Speaking in mathematical sense - `std::set` define equality by its weak ordering by this formula:

```
  a == b  <==>  !(a < b) && !(b < a)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am storing objects of A in a set. I am provide a comparator class which provides implementation of operator() ( A &ob1, A & ob2 ).

That is not correct. The container `std::set` maintains the elements ordered according to the comparator that is configured in the second template argument. To guarantee that the order invariant is not broken, the container stores the keys as constant objects, and that in turn means that the comparator must take the keys by `const &`.

In general, comparators should offer `operator()` that takes two elements by const-reference and the member function should be `const` itself:

```
struct comparator : std::binary_function<A,A,bool> {
   bool operator()( A const& lhs, A const& rhs ) const;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use set.find or set.count, set::find() returns set::end() if element is not found, similary count is zero if element is not found..

```
set<Item*> itemSet;

Item* item = new Item();    

if (itemSet.count(item) == 0)
{
    std::cout<<"not found"
}
//or
if (itemSet.find(item) == itemSet.end())
{
    std::cout<<"not found"
}
```